# Initialization of Bool and Int

Tags: objective-c

I have following code in my project.

I am getting warnings as mentioned  below:
1.'Assuming selectedView is >=0 '
2. Assuming mode_ChangeEvent is 0

```
BOOL modeChangeEvent = NO;
BOOL invokedByUser = NO;
int currentZoomedView = -1;
int prevButIdx = -1;

-(IBAction)zoomSelectedView:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *viewSelector = (UISegmentedControl*)sender; 

    int selectedView =  viewSelector.selectedSegmentIndex;    

    if (selectedView>=0) {  //Warning 'Assuming selectedView is >=0 '

        invoked_ByUser = NO;

    }
else return;


    if (mode_ChangeEvent) { //Warning 'Assuming mode_ChangeEvent is 0 '

        invoked_ByUser = NO;    

        mode_ChangeEvent = NO;

        selectedView = current_ZoomedView;  

        prev_ButIdx = -1;
    }
```

How to get rid off these warnings?

Comment: what is the __real__ warning?

Comment: warning is 'passed-by-value struct argument contains uninitialized value'

Comment: I can't see any struct in your posted code

Comment: I think the variable name you have defined is used in some other conatant like enum or ....